# Change HTML Theme of a specific port

Tags: ftp, themes, server, proftpd

I want know that how can we change the theme of page of a specific port from default listing to custom looking theme.

I am looking to change my FTP port 21's theme from default to custom, dont exactly know how to..

Comment: Can you clarify what you are talking about here? An FTP port doesn't have a "page" with themes. Is this in the context of an application? Which one?

Comment: FTP as is WEB Interface :)

Comment: Pure FTP doesn't have a web interface. What software are you using exactly?

Comment: But Proftpd doesn't appear to come with a web server that could serve HTML pages. You need to find out what product you are using to do that